# How to get a list of place types from the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to programatically get a list of all of the valid place types for search requests. I can look at [the list here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types), but would like to be able to query the server and get a json list so I can keep it up to date automatically instead of having to check the linked page periodically.

Is there an API for that?

Comment: Have you found out how?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.